# Why am I getting a down arrow in my Unity scene when using Oculus Rift and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: unity, oculus

In Unity, I have set up a scene to try out in Oculus Rift. When I hit play in Unity, everything works fine until about 5 seconds later when I get an arrow (Assets>OVR>Textures>out.png) that appears in the center of my screen and won't go away. What does this arrow mean and how can I get rid of it? It is obstructing my view of the level that I am trying to view.

[image: LargeDownArrow]

Comment: Have you considered asking in the dedicated support venues for the software in question?

Comment: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/why-am-i-getting-a-down-arrow-in-my-unity-scene-when-using-oculus-rift-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it.355899/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dshanker from Unity forums answered this question as follows:

*This is a pretty recent feature in the Oculus Unity integration. It's basically a guide that starts to appear when you approach the bounds of the positional tracking camera.
This symbol is basically telling you, "please move your head down, you're near the upper limit of the positional tracker"*

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at your monitor while developing for vr and you vr headset is off to the side then after a few second, this will appear on screen. I guess the trick is to hold the headset by your chin (assuming you don't want to put it on at the moment) to get a quick look at you environment. dshanker is correct.